# Ошибка при создании signed apk

Tags: android

Не могу создать signed apk.

> Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 3s 734ms
>   14:25:26 Generate Signed APK: Errors while building APK. You can find the errors in the 'Messages' view.

В Message

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
>    java.io.IOException: Failed to create 'C:\Users\Dima\Documents\apprtmnts\app\app-release.apk'

Неподписанный апк создается нормально.

Comment: В папке где должен находится apk, при после ошибки создается старая копия подписанного apk

Comment: попробуйте перед билдом АПК вручную удалить старый файл. Еще возможно студия запущена не от имени администратора, и у нее просто нет прав на запись файла в вашу папку